# Tikzpicture infinite curve drawing

Tags: pgfplots

I am drawing an elliptic curve on LaTeX using `tikzpicture`. I have got the graph on the picture, the curve is defined at -2 but I don't know why the graph is not finished.

[image]

Here there is the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-1.912931:3,      
        samples=200,
        smooth,   
        clip=false,
        % use same unit vectors on the axis
        axis equal image=true,
    ]
\addplot[blue] {sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)} node[right] {$E$};
\addplot[blue] {-sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};
\coordinate[label={10:$P$}] (P) at (axis cs:-1,2.64);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "is not finished"? Does not close at -2? Maybe your specified domain does not fit (WolframAlpha means something at about -2.279 as approximation).

Comment: I mean the blue curve is not displayed near -2

Comment: at `x=-2` the valur of your function is `sqrt{3}` which is approximately 1,7320508075688772935274463415059 ..., so your result on selected domain is complete.

Comment: that is right, but on the graph it is not, why ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You selected a domain of `-1.912931:3`. With a corrected domain it (nearly) works (result from `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(sqrt(x^3-3*x%2B5))+%3D+0`).

[image: function]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2.279018:3,      
        samples=201,
        smooth,   
        clip=false,
        % use same unit vectors on the axis
        axis equal image=true,
    ]
\addplot[blue] {sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)} node[right] {$E$};
\addplot[blue] {-sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};
\coordinate[label={10:$P$}] (P) at (axis cs:-1,2.64);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you @TeXnician, it works, but how do I know the correct domain ad sample to use for each function plot ? I can't find a tutorial on that.

Comment: @HindDev That's math. I've just asked WolframAlpha to calculate `abs(sqrt(x^3-3*x+5))=0` and then got the domain. For the samples you were not bad with 200 (I've chosen the 201 just to see if it changes the last unclosed bit, but it didn't work out).

Answer (score 8):

just illustration what you doing:

[image]

blue lines belong to your mwe, red one is on not defined domain:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-3,    xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,    ymax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        clip=false,
        domain=-2.279:3,    % <-- as sugested by TeXnician
        samples=101,
        % use same unit vectors on the axis
        axis equal image=true,
    ]
\addplot[red,domain=-2.279:-2]  {sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};
\addplot[blue,domain=-2:3]      {sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)} node[right] {$E$};
\addplot[red,domain=-2.279:-2]  {-sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};
\addplot[blue,domain=-2:3]      {-sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};
\coordinate[pin=120:{$(-2.279,0)$}]     (aux) at (-2.279,0);
\coordinate[pin=120:{$(-2,\sqrt{3})$}]  (aux) at (-2,1.73205);
\draw[densely dashed, very thin] (-2,-5) -- (-2,5);
\coordinate[label={10:$P$}] (P) at (-1,2.64);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```